# How to create squared glow?

Tags: rendering

There is this square glow effect that a very kind person did for me in Blender:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dmER.png]

The issue is, how does one do this effect?

Is there an option to separate the glow?

Or would one have to create several transparent planes which overlay each other? This would be cumbersome?

Many thanks

Comment: Also, how could this be integrating into an animation (i.e. the glow rotates around to produce a nice effect)? Thanks again ;)

Comment: I bet for layered transparent meshes. We can see the edges on the circle ones... So, it's just modeling, with a bit of texturing / compositing, I think.

Comment: As the person who made this, I can say that it's all materials (no compositing) with a bunch of planes. They could be animated fairly easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That image was created with a bunch of overlapping transparent planes which were created by extruding parts of a circle:

1. Add a circle (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>*> Mesh > Circle*. Note that you may want to increase the *Vertices* in the redo menu for a smother curve.) Then delete some of the vertices so you only have part of a circle:

   [image]
2. Extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>) and cancel the transform to leave the extruded vertices where they are (<kbd>Esc</kbd>). Then scale along the normals with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> so you have this shape:

   [image]
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 varying the amount of vertices you delete from the circle until you have several different sizes. Then duplicate (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) rotate (<kbd>R</kbd>) them around (make sure you move them slightly on the Z axis to avoid Z-fighting) so you have something like this:

   [image]
4. Duplicate and rotate the entire bunch a couple times for good measure (again moving on the Z-axis) and add a couple circles for effect:

   [image]
5. Add a material for additive blending (see [How to get additive blending in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5331/599)):

   [image]
6. Insert a rotation keyframe for all of them (press <kbd>I</kbd>*> Rotation* to insert a keyframe on the selected objects), then go to a later frame and run *Randomize Transform* (<kbd>Space</kbd>*> Search > Randomize Transform*). In the *Redo menu* at the bottom of the *Tool shelf* (<kbd>N</kbd> in the *3D view*), Enable *Randomize Rotation* and set the Z to 180. Then insert another *Rotation keyframe*.

### Result:

[animated gif http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=65211](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=65211)

**[blendfile](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/26233)**