# Blender Internal renderer question

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

How do I enable, for example, additive blending for a material? Do I need to use node? I am trying out to create a light ball.

I searched the internet but only found answers for cycles.

Edit:
The result should be like the first picture in this topic: [How to get additive blending in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5331/how-to-get-additive-blending-in-cycles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using nodes would be only way to make additive blending for material.
Though If You're making a light ball in Blender Internal You don't need it. Just go to material, find Shading make Emit higher then 1, go to World, check Indirect Lighting switch Gather(right below Indirect Lighting) to Approximate and voila, You got ball, that emits light.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Can you tell me what do I need to do if I use node? I want to learn it just in case I need to other blending mode in the future.

Comment: Here is pretty nice [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FaQcMAjg6Jc) on the topic of using material nodes in BI. For making light ball though I wouldn't use material nodes, cause it would be like painting with Your foot instead of Your hand - exercise in futility

Comment: Thank you. But if I understand it correctly, the material needs to blend with the background and object behind it in order to create the transparent effect. However from the video the material node only changes the material itself. :)

Comment: I guess You should be more specific on what You plan to do, cause you didn't mention anything about transparent effect earlier.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mean additive blending like in this question(the ball showed in the first picture), but with blender internal render. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5331/how-to-get-additive-blending-in-cycles

Comment: If You need the material to additively blend with the background and other objects, without using compositing, then I don't think there is a way to do that in BI. There is just not enough information that you could extract from the scene to use in material, no Z-depth node or anything similar.

Comment: Thank you again. I think I understand now. :) I don't mind using compositing, if it is the only way.